# Using two ScrollTop() functions in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a single page website which uses smooth scrolling to anchors for navigation. I'm also trying to add a 'back to the top' button but can't seem to get the animation working (clicking the button doesn't do anything). I believe it's because I'm using two scrollTop functions. Is this correct and how can I solve this?

```
    // Smooth scrolling for page anchors
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1000, 'swing');
    });

});
// Sticky back to top button
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
            $('.go-top').fadeIn("500");
        } else {
            $('.go-top').fadeOut("500");
        }
    });
    $('.go-top').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What's in `.go-top` element?

Comment: The latter function can scroll smooth at my browser

Comment: The .go-top element is the sticky button which should scroll to the top of the page once clicked. It's simply this:
<a href="#" class="go-top"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span></a>

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - I had to removed the second `$(document).ready(function () {` line of code.